when people thought they'd seen a ghost
Suppose John is an innkeeper at a hotel rumored to be haunted. Peter wants to stay there, so he walks up to the reception desk and says: "Hi, I'd like to stay at this hotel for a couple of days, but I heard it's haunted. Is that true?" John replies:
1. Well, I don't believe in all that ghost talk, but there have been times when people thought they'd seen a ghost.
2. Well, I don't believe in all that ghost talk, but there have been times when people thought they've seen a ghost.
3. Well, I don't believe in all that ghost talk, but there have been times when people've thought they've seen a ghost.
Which version should be used in this case? If more than one is acceptable, which ones are, and do you have a preference? I'm wondering about the tenses in bold. Thanks.

Any would be acceptable. To my purist’s ear, though, better than any of them is *…there have been times when people have thought they had seen a ghost. At the time of the thinking, the supposed seeing was already in the past, thus the past perfect.

Americans tend to avoid perfect tenses. They'd just say "When people thought they saw a ghost".

My intuition is that perfect (present or past) is more common with seeing a ghost than with many other events. It just seems to be a common way of discussing ghost sightings: "Have you ever seen a ghost?" "He looked like he had seen a ghost" etc.

I disagree with Barmar.  Plenty of Americans use perfect tenses all the time.

I find (2) (they thought they have) unacceptable. Either they thought they had or they have thought they have.

These are the ones I find most idiomatic:

... but there are times when people think they've seen a ghost


... but there were times when people thought they saw a ghost


... but there have been times when people have thought they'd seen a ghost

